# Initialize a number of instances inside a list

Tags: c#

any more efficient or shorter way to initialize a number of instance inside a List<>

```
List<SomeObject> contrats = new List<SomeObject>();
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) 
     contrats.Add(new SomeObject());
```

Comment: You can do things like `Enumerable.Range(0, rowCount).Select(x => new SomeObject()).ToList()`, but it's not that much neater. One small improvement to your current approach would be `new List<SomeObject>(rowCount)`

Comment: Your current approach is pretty fine already